# Bootstrap 3 table-responsive background-color issue on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having an issue with the Bootstrap 3 table-responsive on iOS 7 (iPad4 on safari).
When I load the webpage with the table it can only show 70% of the table and the rest is hidden to the right:
[image]

But the issue is when i scroll to the right the background color of the table is lost and the background of the body is shown:
[image]

I've simplified the table as much as possible to weed out anything silly i missed with no luck. Here is how the body is defined (i removed the table info because it's being created by some ng-repeats and aren't helpful):

```
<body style="background-color: #3E3E40;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table" style="background-color: #E0E0E3;">
         ....
      </table>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
```

Any information or suggestions on how to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/qYY2y/

HTML is unchanged, I'm applying the table background color to table-responsive div that wraps your table

```
.table-responsive{
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
A variation for [@rapcal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646621/rapcal) with a drop shadow on the responsive table
 http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/16yt4vnq/

Applying a drop shadow to the table directly won't work because of how the native bootstrap stying handles overflows on the table-responsive div. But if you wrap everything in another div you have more freedom

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- apply drop shadow to this div -->
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table"> ... </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried so many things i can't remember if i tried this one. I will try it first thing tomorrow! Thanks!!

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you very much for your help! Weird that this only happens on safari in iOS.

Comment: Good tip, @DavidTaiaroa! Unfortunately if you have box-shadow on the table this won't work

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, @DavidTaiaroa! Works :+1: